# Java / Groovy - Memory leak in GroovyClassLoader

Tags: java, groovy, memory-leaks, classloader

I'm loading a large number of Groovy (2.4.6) scripts and running them using [GroovyScriptEngineImpl](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.6/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/jsr223/GroovyScriptEngineImpl.html) in my Java 8 application and I'm running into a problem after a while.

There is a few things that you need to know :

- I have to recreate a new `GroovyScriptEngineImpl` every time I run a script
- I have to recreate a new `GroovyClassLoader` every time I run a script

I need to do it like that in order to isolate each script in a separate "environment": I'm loading some external JARs in the classloader for some scripts and I don't want other scripts to be able to use the classes in those JARs when they're executed.

My problem comes from the fact that for every script that I run, the `GroovyClassLoader` will create a new `ScriptXXXX` class and load it, but never unload it.

This results in the number of classes loaded increasing indefinitly and the memory ending up being totally filled.

I have tried a huge amount of various solutions, but none seem to work :

- Adding `-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` in the JVM arguments
- Adding `-Dgroovy.use.classvalue=true` in the JVM arguments
- Removing the "meta classes" created for each `ScriptXXXX` class as shown here : [Groovy Classes not being collected but not signs of memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506291/groovy-classes-not-being-collected-but-not-signs-of-memory-leak)
- Clearing the cache and closing the `GroovyClassLoader`
- Using introspection to manually clear some fields caching the classes in the `GroovyScriptEngineImpl`
- etc...

Here's the "Shortest path to GC" for one of the `ScriptXXXX` class in Eclipse Memory Analyzer :

[image: Eclipse Memory Analyzer dump]

I'm clearly running out of solutions here, and none seem to really work as the class loader always keeps a reference to the classes which are never getting GCed.

If you want to reproduce the issue, here's a code sample :

```
GroovyScriptEngineImpl se;

while (true)
{
    se = new GroovyScriptEngineImpl(new GroovyClassLoader());
    CompiledScript script = se.compile("println(\"hello\")");
    script.eval(se.createBindings());
}
```

Thanks

**UPDATE** : After reading pczeus's reply, I tried limiting the metaspace, and some classes seem to be unloading indeed, and I think that it's the `ScriptXXX` classes.

That said, after a few minutes I'm getting `Out of Metaspace` errors during the script execution.

Here's the profile I'm getting with the VisualVM :

[image: Profile in the Java VisualVM]

And the "Path to GC" in Eclipse Memory Analyzer for the `ScriptXXX` classes are indeed empty (their's no more instance of the classes), even tho the class is still listed in the histogram.

Comment: How many is a "large number" of scripts?

Comment: Potentially unlimited. Actually their might be only a few different scripts, but as I said they have to have an isolated environment and so they're being recompiled every time. As an example, I ran a test during 1 hour which created about 10,000 scripts and used 1GB of RAM. And even with a lower amount of scripts, the application will be a server that shouldn't be restarted too often, so the number of `ScriptXXX` classes is going to increase anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by you want to isolate each script in a separate environment? If you are using the same script cache then how two different evaluation going to impact each other?

Comment: I'm loading some external JAR in the class loader for some script execution and I don't want other scripts to access be able to access the classes in those JARs when they are executed, which would be the case if I was using the same classloader and script engine.

Comment: This sounds like a fairly narrow use case and I think this will require more detailed investigation than can be done here unless you want to provide a solid workable representation of the code with its issues. I think the best you can do it profile it and find ways to clean things up and/or minimize resource allocation.

Comment: Well the code at the end of my post has the exact problem that I'm facing : It creates a `ScriptXXX` class on each turn of the loop, and no matter what I do, those classes are not released by the classloader, and not GCed, which ends up filling the memory. The part about the isolation is not important in itself, you just have to know that I have to recompile the scripts on every execution, and that I have to use a new `GroovyScriptEngineImpl` and a new `GroovyClassLoader` on every execution.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? I'm using `Eval.x` at many places in my code and I'm seeing huge number of `ScriptX` classes when analyzing the heap dump.

Comment: @HardikModha Nope. I stopped working for the company where I developed this software so I don't know if they ended up fixing it but what I did was to cache the scripts when I was reusing them. So basically I store the `GroovyClassLoader` for each new script and then reuse it. It has issues (for example static variables are not reset...) but it's a workaround...

Comment: Thanks for the update. In my case, I removed all the `Eval.x` from my code and implemented my own method and it worked pretty well.

Comment: @HardikModha, we are bumping on the same issue - can you share your custom eval?

Answer (score 2):

This definitely appears to be somewhat of an edge case that requires special tuning and possibly choosing the garbage collection scheme used.

Since you are using Java8, and you know you are loading thousands of temporary classes, you should try to tune and limit the amount of `MetaSpace` available and tune the frequency of cleanup. Straight from https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/entry/about_g1_garbage_collector_permanent :

> JDK8: Metaspace
>
> In JDK 8, classes metadata is now stored in the native heap and this space is called Metaspace. There are some new flags added for Metaspace in JDK 8:
>
> -XX:MetaspaceSize= where  is the initial amount of space(the initial high-water-mark) allocated for class metadata (in bytes) that may induce a garbage collection to unload classes. The amount is approximate. After the high-water-mark is first reached, the next high-water-mark is managed by the garbage collector
>
> -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize= where  is the maximum amount of space to be allocated for class metadata (in bytes). This flag can be used to limit the amount of space allocated for class metadata. This value is approximate. By default there is no limit set.
>   -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio= where  is the minimum percentage of class metadata capacity free after a GC to avoid an increase in the amount of space (high-water-mark) allocated for class metadata that will induce a garbage collection.
>
> -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio= where  is the maximum percentage of class metadata capacity free after a GC to avoid a reduction in the amount of space (high-water-mark) allocated for class metadata that will induce a garbage collection.
>
> By default class metadata allocation is only limited by the amount of available native memory. We can use the new option MaxMetaspaceSize to limit the amount of native memory used for the class metadata. It is analogous to MaxPermSize. A garbage collection is induced to collect the dead classloaders and classes when the class metadata usage reaches MetaspaceSize (12Mbytes on the 32bit client VM and 16Mbytes on the 32bit server VM with larger sizes on the 64bit VMs). Set MetaspaceSize to a higher value to delay the induced garbage collections. After an induced garbage collection, the class metadata usage needed to induce the next garbage collection may be increased.